# How to add checkbox to select entire group in the angular material drop down?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have requirement on mat-select element. I have group of values in drop down, which will appear like attached image [image: Dropdown requirement]

Here [Link to work around](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-ntbkgk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.css) i have done some work around here but that does not reach my requirement, i am stuck here and i could not achieve the requirement. here every subgroups has checkbox to select but if i select child values one by one inside subgroup. once after selecting all the child values subgroup should be selected automatically but this is not happening and also expand and collapse icons are not working properly. like once if we expand, collapse icon should display there. please help me here to achieve the requirement and any answer would be appreciated. Thanks for the help in advance...
this is what i have tried in my local....

app.component.html:->

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>

  <mat-select [formControl]="states" multiple>
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{states.value ? states.value[0] : ''}}
      <span *ngIf="states.value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
        (+{{states.value.length - 1}} {{states.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
      </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>

    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of stateList">
      <div>
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="group.selected" (change)="toggleParent($event, group)"
                      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          {{group.letter}}
        </mat-checkbox>
        <button mat-button (click)="expandDocumentTypes(group)">
          <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let name of group.names" [value]="name"
                  [ngClass]="isExpandCategory[group.letter] ? 'list-show' : 'list-hide'" (selectionChange)="greet($event)">
        {{name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

app.component.scss:->

```
.example-additional-selection {
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.list-hide {
  display: none;
}

.list-show {
  display: block;
}
```

app.component.html:->

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatCheckboxChange } from '@angular/material/checkbox';

export interface StateGroup {
  letter: string;
  checked: boolean;
  names: string[];
}


interface Subgroup {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Group {
  name: string;
  subgroups: Subgroup[];
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  // stateForm: FormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  //   stateGroup: '',
  // });
  // toppings = new FormControl();
  isExpandCategory: boolean[] = [];
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
  stateRecord: any = [];
  states = new FormControl();

  expandDocumentTypes(group: any) {
    console.log("expanding dropdown", group);
    this.isExpandCategory[group.letter] = !this.isExpandCategory[group.letter];
    // expand only selected parent dropdown category with that childs
  }

  toggleSelection(event: any, name: any, group: any) {
    /*  debugger;*/
    console.log("toggleSelection", name, event.checked, group);
    if (event.checked) {
      console.log("stastateRecordtelist", this.stateRecord);
      this.stateRecord.push(name);
      this.states.setValue(this.stateRecord);
      console.log("toggleselection ", this.states.value);
    }
    else {
      this.stateRecord = this.stateRecord.filter((x: any) => x !== name);
      console.log("else toggleselection", name, group, this.states.value);
      this.states.setValue(this.states.value.filter((x: any) => x !== name));
      console.log("after filter ", this.states.value);
      //this.states.setValue([]);
    }
  }

  toggleParent(event: any, group: any) {
    /*    debugger;*/
    group.checked = event.checked;
    console.log("event", event.checked, "group", group, "states value", this.states.value);
    let states = this.states.value;
    states = states ? states : [];
    if (event.checked) {
      states.push(...group.names)
    } else {
      console.log("else", states);
      group.names.forEach((x: string) => {
        if (states.indexOf(x) > -1) {
          states.splice(states.indexOf(x), 1)
        }
      });
    }
    this.states.setValue(states);
    console.log("statesvalue", this.states.value);
    if (!event.checked) {
      this.states.setValue(this.states.value.filter((x: any) => !x.includes(group.names)))
      //this.states.setValue([]);
    }
    this.stateRecord = this.states.value;
    console.log("final statesvalue", this.states.value);
  }

  stateList: any = [{
    letter: 'A',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas']
  }, {
    letter: 'C',
    checked: false,
    names: ['California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut']
  }, {
    letter: 'D',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Delaware']
  }, {
    letter: 'F',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Florida']
  }, {
    letter: 'G',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Georgia']
  }, {
    letter: 'H',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Hawaii']
  }, {
    letter: 'I',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa']
  }, {
    letter: 'K',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Kansas', 'Kentucky']
  }, {
    letter: 'L',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Louisiana']
  }, {
    letter: 'M',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan',
      'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana']
  }, {
    letter: 'N',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey',
      'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota']
  }, {
    letter: 'O',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon']
  }, {
    letter: 'P',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Pennsylvania']
  }, {
    letter: 'R',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Rhode Island']
  }, {
    letter: 'S',
    checked: false,
    names: ['South Carolina', 'South Dakota']
  }, {
    letter: 'T',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Tennessee', 'Texas']
  }, {
    letter: 'U',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Utah']
  }, {
    letter: 'V',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Vermont', 'Virginia']
  }, {
    letter: 'W',
    checked: false,
    names: ['Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']
  }];

  greet(event:any):void {
    console.log("called grret method::", event);
  }

}
```

and also i have attached my output[image: my local output], please have a look... and thanks...

Comment: You should post your code and what you've tried.

Comment: Can't you see a link of stackblitz? i hope that's more than enough. if you are unable look at my code let me know...

Comment: Post your code, not a link to your code.  The point of this site is to answer questions *and have them be useful to others*.  Leaving out details and putting them on a site which is not indexed by the search and can change later only benefits you in the short term.

Comment: Hopefully now you can see my code...

Comment: You can set the value in `states` formControl on click of group header.